# iOS 8.0 Wrong interfaceOrientation during layoutSubviews

Tags: ios, ios8

I have a delegate in my custom view where I can ask my View Controller what the current interfaceOrientation is.  I'm getting back the previous interfaceOrientation.  If I manually call layoutSubviews after rotation (didRotate) it works.

This code has worked on previous versions of iOS.

How can I get the interfaceOrientation that is being rotated TO during layoutSubviews?

Comment: As a workaround, I'm getting the To-Orientation from [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation] and it's working as expected.